# SASS / HandlebarsJS conflicts?

Tags: css, sass, handlebars.js

Background: For a project, I am trying to use SASS and Handlebars to create a vote counter that displays a stored value from my database and updates when a user presses the up or down vote buttons.

Are there any known interactions/conflicts that would causes SASS styling to not be applied when used with Handlebars or vice-versa?

For reference, here is the code I have in my HTML that I am working with.

```
<div id='voteWrapper'>
    <script id='voteTile' type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#each proTipVote}}
      <div class="vote circle">
        <div class="increment up" data-id={{_id}}></div>
        <div class="increment down" data-id={{_id}}></div>
        <div class="count" data-id={{_id}}>{{tipScore}}</div>
      </div>
      {{/each}}
    </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: SASS is just a CSS compiler, and handlebar is templating engine, so any issue would be between your compiled CSS and your handlebar rendered HTML.  The `data-id={{_id}}` looks suspicious to me.  Looks like that should probably be `data-id="{{_id}}"`. HTML attribute values should be in quotes.

Comment: I'm still very new to SASS/Handlebars so forgive me if my questions are basic.

I added the quotes to the IDs and it did not cause any changes but I will incorporate that habit into my code going forward, thank you! 

My concerns were that there were some crossovers in syntax between Handlebars & SASS that were causing my styles not to show.

Comment: Can you post your compiled css and source code?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your efforts to help me.

I asked my friend to look at my code and he found that I wasn't calling my render function at the beginning.